# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: Internal Error concurrentHashTable.inline.hpp:676

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm

I have no idea what went wrong as I've programmed in Java 17. When I run a spring-boot project, it starts normally and then suddenly goes down and now I get this error:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  Internal Error (concurrentHashTable.inline.hpp:676), pid=10956, tid=41731
  fatal error: aux_index does not match even or odd indices

 JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-8552009 (17.0.9+8) (build 17.0.9+8-LTS)
 Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Microsoft-8552009 (17.0.9+8-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, bsd-aarch64)
 No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   https://github.com/microsoft/openjdk/issues
```

Can someone help me? Thank you very much

Comment: There is a similar bug report already: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8233525 but it seems there is no solution provided.

Comment: Is this a bug in openjdk？

Comment: For me the description in the bug report sumarizes as: "Some code is messing with the JVM internals and then the JVM just crashes instead of trying to handle the problem." I don't think they treat it as a bug in openjdk. But if you can provide them some example code that triggers the problem without doing something invalid then they might reconsider the severity.